# Are time complexity of followng codes equivalent?

Tags: algorithms

Implemented is done in C++.

Supposing we have defined a class `T` with no restrictions and three functions `cond`, `next` and `f` returning `bool`, `void` and anything respectively, are

```
for(T k = T(); cond(); next())
    f();
```

and

```
{
T k = T();

while(cond()) {
    f();
    next();
}
}
```

So, I would like know that time complexity of the following algorithms are same?

Comment: Programming questions are off topic here.

Comment: If the while loop always runs 100 times slower then time complexity is the same. Same if the while loop always runs 100 times faster.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not familiar with `C++` but it looks like that both codes are equivalent, `for` loop and `while` loop has the same power.

In your examples, in both cases you first you initial the variable `k`, and  the loop doesn't stop as `coud()` condition holds, inside the loop there is a call to `f();` method, and finally to `next();`.

Answer (score 0):

As your code stands, yes they are algorithmically the same in that both have a starting state, a condition, and an incrementing step.

The difference between the two would be if the code within the body of the `for` and the `while` had a `continue` statement. With a `for` the `continue` statement would cause the `next()` to be executed before the condition is checked since the `next()` is part of the `for` and not part of the body of the `for`.

However with the `while` a `continue` statement that is before the `next()` would cause execution to jump to the end of the `while` body which would bypass the `next()`. This would result in `next()` not be called with a possible infinite loop. This is because the `next()` is within the body of the `while`.